# fstab и "временно" отключенные диски

Tags: linux, hdd, mount, fstab

Два винта основной и дополнительный, который иногда могу отключать.
Также сегодня пришлось подключить третий (мой sdb стал sdc), чтобы восстановить данные. В обеих случаях система "выпала" в emergency и не грузилась. Пришлось править fstab, и перегружать.

Как избежать подобных неприятностей? Просто игнорировать отсутствующие разделы в fstab. Ну ещё лучше, что система "нашла" перемещённый раздел с sdb в sdc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Как избежать подобных неприятностей? Просто игнорировать отсутствующие разделы в fstab.

Можно и так, зависит от системы инициализации, но в большинстве случаев (для sysvinit, openrc, upstart, systemd) надо добавить `nofail` в параметры монтирования для некритичных разделов.

```
/dev/sdb6      /games      btrfs   nofail        1 2
```

> Ну ещё лучше, что система "нашла" перемещённый раздел с sdb в sdc?

Тогда нужно использовать другие способы ссылаться на устройство вместо прямого указания `/dev/sdXN`, например симлинки из `/dev/disk/by-*`. Наиболее практичные варианты — `by-id`, `by-uuid` и `by-label`. Также вместо последних двух можно прописать 
`UUID=aa...-.-.-.-...ee` и `LABEL=my_fs_label` соответственно.

```
/dev/by-id/ata-Hitachi_HDT725032VLA360_VFD200R3CTNK4L-part5 /home  ext4     defaults        1 2
UUID=6640d0fc-c41e-41fd-af1e-d7d804e64c87                   /var   reiserfs defaults        1 2
LABEL=linux_usr                                             /usr   ext4     defaults        1 2
```

Также, как вариант, можно упомянуть lvm — он также не чувствителен к физическому расположению разделов, но это уже другая история...

Comment: Спасибо. А если я уже "попал" в emergency есть ли более простой способ загрузить систему, не правя fstab? Кстати, а что такое "by-path"?

Comment: @YuchimenkoIgor, имел в виду by-id — уже поправил... by-path — это по внутреннему представлению пути по слоям используемых драйверов, относительно мало полезен... а про правку — с трудом представляю, что может быть проще, чем поправить один файл

Comment: $ ls -la /dev/disk/by-* я так понял можно увидеть где какой диск.
А что если, окажется два диска с одинаковой меткой (LABEL=Windows)? Это конечно маловероятно, но всё-же...

Comment: в доках не видел спецификацию поведения, а на практике, честно признаться, никогда не пробовал... так что вперёд — вряд ли это закончится нападением акул...